# Abcpdf HttpContent.Create FileNotFoundException in ASP.net mvc context but file exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, pdf, abcpdf

I use Abcpdf,

Sometimes I get in production FileNotFoundException after creation of HttpMultipartMimeForm with path use by the `HttpContent.Create(` methode

The major part of time this code works well

The PDF is creat in context where

1. ASP.NET website A is called
2. A call website B to generate the PDF
3. Website B call url on B for HTML to PDF abcpdf method.
4. After previous request to B is finish, website A send file to server C via HttpClient HttpMultipartMimeForm and Exception is throw sometimes, but when I look on the server the file exist

A and B is on the same machine and sharing the same directories.

I supposed that the file is not finish to write on disk when I try to acces on it. But how to resolved this ?

Thanks.

**1. Server A**

```
using (HttpClient pdfClient = new HttpClient("http://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xxx"]))
{
    using (HttpResponseMessage message = pdfClient.Get(UrlDictionary.callxxx(xxxID, xxxID)))
    {
        message.EnsureStatusIsSuccessful();
        message.Content.ReadAsStream();
    }
}
```

**2. Server B**

```
theDoc.Save(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "/xxx/" + ".pdf");
theDoc.Clear();
```

**3. Server A**

```
 HttpMultipartMimeForm request = new HttpMultipartMimeForm();

  FileInfo info = new FileInfo(pathFile);
  HttpFormFile file = new HttpFormFile();
  file.Content = **HttpContent.Create(info, "multipart/form-data")**; (Exception FileNotFoundException)
  file.FileName = info.Name;
  file.Name = "file";


  request.Files.Add(file);
  request.Add("id", id);

  using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.Post(
      string.Format("/xxx/{0}", id), 
      request.CreateHttpContent()))
  {
      ExceptionIfBadRequest(response);
      Contrat contrat = (Contrat)FromXml(response.Content.ReadAsString(), typeof(Contrat));
      return contrat;
  }
```

Comment: Your exception is very clear, the file in the directory you are searching in

Comment: But after I look on production server the file exist

Comment: debug your code by stepping into it and check if the directory path is even right

Comment: Yes but code works on production major part of time.

Comment: I can log in production but log what ?

Comment: if so why not thread the processes and lock it when one already access to the file and release it to the other when the first one finishes?

Comment: Thank you for the idea, Have you an example ?

Comment: Or make a retry catch excpetion ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on the PDF file and the directory, check the file doesn't have some 'zone' information attached to it.

Comment: Yes but this code works major part of time, so this is not a permission problem, I thinks...